# How to use redirect() outside controller in zend 2

Tags: zend-framework2

```
$renderer = $sm->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface'); 
$url = $renderer->basePath('/album/index/login');   
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
```

Above code work in controller but not in module.php

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Controller plugin within your module.php this could fail on when exactly you call this within your event chain, though.

```
$sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$redirect = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('redirect');
$renderer = $sm->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface'); 
$url = $renderer->basePath('/album/index/login'); 
$redirect->toUrl($url)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Your code worked but I found other way to do this.$target         = $e->getTarget(); 
return $target->redirect()->toUrl($e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() .'/album/index/login');